# Как при наведении на 1 элемент менять видимость псевдоэлемента 2 элемента?

Tags: html, css

Очень простой вопрос, но что-то пробую и не получается.

Требуется при наведение на `block2` менять `block1:after` на `display:none`.

Пробовал вот такую конструкцию:

```
block2:hover block1:after {
 display:none;
}
```

Не сработала (

```css
.block1 {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.block1::after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.block2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```

Comment: можно только если местами поменять. в css есть возможность выбрать только следующий элемент – `.block1:hover ~ .block2:after { ... }`, а нааборот никак

Comment: Можно через js
При наведении на block2 добавлять блоку "block1" класс, у которого after display: none;

Answer (score 0):

Средствами css невозможно реализовать обращение к предыдущему блоку, только к последующим или внутренним.

Разве что с костылями:

```css
.block1 {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.block1::after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.block2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.block2 {
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  left: 0;
}

.block2:hover ~ .block1::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">    
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block1"></div>
</div>
```

Поэтому есть вариант с jquery:

```js
$('.block2').hover(
  function(){
    $('.block1').addClass('hover');
  },
  function(){
    $('.block1').removeClass('hover');
  }
);
```

```css
.block1 {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.block1::after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.block2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.block1.hover::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```